# Самый точный таймер обратного отсчета для онлайн аукциона

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, yii2, redis

работаю над онлайн аукционом. Встал момент таймера обратного отсчета, в базе данных хранится дата окончания аукциона. Испробовал множество плагинов и различных решений, но увы все таймеры очень не точные(разница во времени до конца аукциона на различных устройствах колеблется от 1 секунды до 20 и выше). Понимаю, что у всех разная техника и вычисление времени у каждого разное, разная скорость интернет подключения. Но как быть, уже перечитал много разной информации но сам дойти к правильному решению не могу. Прошу совета у вас коллеги. Как сделать точный таймер обратного отсчета, что бы у всех пользователей время было максимально одинаковым(точным)? Использую за основу Yii2 + MySQL + WebSocket(nodejs + socket.io + redis).

Comment: В браузере? никак. или на стороне сервера делайте, или забейте на "точность" =)

Comment: А можно по подробней за серверное решение?

Comment: Ну а как вариант, что отправляется системное время из браузера, сервер считает разницу во времени и отправляет обратно уровень поправки?

Comment: Забыть про точность данных на клиенте, я вам говорю об этом, ну не добьетесь вы никак точности на разных машинах в браузере =) если вам нужна точность то добится ее можно только на стороне сервера, т.е. сервер будет отрабатывать в точно положеное время(до десятков микросекунд), а на клиентах у вас так и будет разброс в десятки секунд

Comment: @ДмитрийПапава Также есть такая платформа kahoot, суть там в том, что вопросы показываются на экране одного компьютера, а ответить можно только с других(викторина интерактивная), так там ээта проблема как-то решена. Там нельзя ответить на вопрос до или после начала или окончания вопроса. И точность там неплохая. Можно там порыться в коде

Comment: Определитесь точно с задачей, вам нужно точно делать какие то действия на стороне клиента, или не допускать действий вне временных промежутков? второе делается на стороне сервера.

Comment: Ну например у человека осталось до конца 2 секунды, через 2 секунды отработает код, который завершит торги, а у другого человека еще 20 секунд до конца, человек рассчитывает сделать ставку в эти 20 секунд, а тут внезапно торги закончились. Как в таком моменте быть?

Comment: Передать человеку на устройство время окончания торгов по UTC например, и дальше уже его личная вина что у него часы на ПК\телефоне идут не правильно.

Comment: Главное на сервере вести время правильно. А на клиент сообщать время в UTC, как было сказано выше, отрисовывать юзеру таймер - сколько ему осталось до конца аукциона, ну и раз в минуту/10 минут/час обновлять страницу или синхронизировать с сервером через сокет или ajax. Как показывает практика, юзеры всё равно будут жать обновить страницу как сумасшедшие :-)

Comment: @nilecrocodile если вы отправили человеку время окончания аукциона в UTC или любом другом формате, но чётко фиксированное время(а не сдвиг времени) - зачем постоянно запрашивать уточнения с сервера особенно с учётом того что они не изменятся!!! сервер всегда будет возвращать точную дату, а клиент считать сколько "секунд" осталось исходя из локального времени ПК, если так хочется предупредить клиента что он сильно рискует пропустить свой шанс - проверьте его локальное время и выведите ему предупреждение в случае расхождения времени =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков на тот случай если таймер на клиенте отстанет. А отстать он может если притормозит браузер, например, в случае если автор реализует обратный отсчет не переинициализируя объект Date, а просто на setInterval-е.

Comment: @nilecrocodile, простите конечно, но вы в своем мире и о своей реализации... 
что в этом "псевдо коде" может отстать?
`До_окончания_аукциона_осталось = разность_дат(точная_дата_окончания_аукциона-текущее_локальное_время)`
текущее локальное время не зависит от браузера, это системное время... время окончания аукциона - неизменно, сказали 9.10.2018 18:00, оно не поменяется ниразу, сколько с сервера его не перезапрашивай. заметте я не предлагаю декрементировать некое значение раз в секунду.. я предлогаю брать системное время. **я ниразу не предлагал делать обратный отсчет(декрементом)**

Comment: @Дмитрий Папава отправляй время с сервера через websocet.